# Position of the verb 'be' near 'whatever'

Tags: conditional-constructions, word-order, subjunctives, conjugations

Which of the following is correct in meaning and why?

1. Whatever the situation be, you must not falter.
2. Whatever be the situation, you must not falter.

Note: The answer should imply this - You must not falter in any situation.

Comment: *Be* is distinctly archaic in this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are okay. It all depends on the writing style.

> **Whatever be the exact number of such cases** the point is that in not a single case has the sanction been given so far... - *Anthropological Quarterly Summer2009, Vol. 82 Issue 3, p691-717, 27p*

And,

> **Whatever the situation be,** this would be Real Madrid’s best chance to win the Champions League in the last decade and complete the ‘La Decima’ and end their 12 year long wait for the 10th Champions League title - *[DNA](http://www.dnaindia.com/sport/comment-this-is-real-madrid-s-best-chance-to-win-the-champions-league-1983704)*

Think the similar concept, we do say - *"Whatever the case is, he is going to win"* and *"Whatever is the case, he is going to win"*

However, natives may help us learn which one is better and preferred.

Comment: You can even leave out _be_ altogether, and end up with a very natural sentence: _Whatever the situation, you must never falter_. To me that sounds even more natural than including _be_ in any position.